# What is the impact of non unique IDs across an Elasticsearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch

The Elasticsearch [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html#_unique_ids_with_custom_routing) says:

> When indexing documents specifying a custom _routing, the uniqueness of the _id is not guaranteed across all of the shards in the index. In fact, documents with the same _id might end up on different shards if indexed with different _routing values.

We are planning to introduce custom routing to our documents, but it would be really convenient if we could just add the routing in our existing index. As expected and according to the docs, newer versions of the document will be in the right shard but the old shard will keep the old versions until we delete them.

Apart from disk space wasted, what are the possible implications of non unique IDs across an Elasticsearch index because it's available on multiple primary shards?